# Lucee - MySQL - Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, lucee

I try to add a new data source, but I get this error:

```
lucee.runtime.exp.NativeException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up. at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110) at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89) at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63) at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73) at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:898) at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:823) at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:448) at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241) at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) at lucee.runtime.db.DataSourceSupport._getConnection(DataSourceSupport.java:135) at lucee.runtime.db.DataSourceSupport.getConnection(DataSourceSupport.java:103) at lucee.runtime.tag.Admin._doVerifyDatasource(Admin.java:2936) at lucee.runtime.tag.Admin.doUpdateDatasource(Admin.java:2712) at lucee.runtime.tag.Admin._doStartTag(Admin.java:742) at lucee.runtime.tag.Admin.doStartTag(Admin.java:355) at services_datasource_create_cfm1334$cf.call(/admin/services.datasource.create.cfm:88) at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl._doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:1015) at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl._doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:938) at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:919) at services_datasource_cfm414$cf.call(/admin/services.datasource.cfm:108) at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl._doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:1015) at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl._doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:938) at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:919) at web_cfm$cf.call(/admin/web.cfm:492) at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl._doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:1015) at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl._doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:938) at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:919) at server_cfm$cf.call(/admin/server.cfm:2) at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl._doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:1015) at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl._doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:938) at lucee.runtime.listener.ModernAppListener._onRequest(ModernAppListener.java:219) at lucee.runtime.listener.MixedAppListener.onRequest(MixedAppListener.java:44) at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.execute(PageContextImpl.java:2482) at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl._execute(PageContextImpl.java:2468) at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.executeCFML(PageContextImpl.java:2439) at lucee.runtime.engine.Request.exe(Request.java:45) at lucee.runtime.engine.CFMLEngineImpl._service(CFMLEngineImpl.java:1198) at lucee.runtime.engine.CFMLEngineImpl.serviceCFML(CFMLEngineImpl.java:1144) at lucee.loader.engine.CFMLEngineWrapper.serviceCFML(CFMLEngineWrapper.java:97) at lucee.loader.servlet.CFMLServlet.service(CFMLServlet.java:51) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) at mod_cfml.core.invoke(core.java:180) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up. ... 65 more Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server. at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:89) at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:120) at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:842) ... 59 more Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt (Connection refused) at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:153) at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63) ... 61 mor
```

[image: Error]

My settings:
[image: IMG1]
[image: IMG2]
[image: IMG3]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Right... so Lucee can't connect to the DB. You haven't told us whether you can connect with the same credentials / settings independent of Lucee, which is fairly vital information? You don't indicate that you've done any troubleshooting / googling of your own (eg: googling the error message and reading what other ppl have done in the same situation. Pls edit the question to get rid of the pictures of the stack trace and just include the _text_ version of the settings you're passing to the DB. Also posting the version of the entire stack trace in a single line is not very usable.

Comment: When creating the datasource, Lucee attempts to immediately connect to the SQL server using the entered information. It will stop after 3 unsucccessful attempts and throw this exception. That means any of the following: the server's address is wrong, the server's port is wrong, the server's address cannot be reached, the server's port is closed or not listening. And as a tip for debugging the connectivity: Remember that the machine where Lucee is running needs to reach the SQL server, not you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first suggestion would be to determine if the Lucee server can even talk to that other server.  If you have RDP or shell access, I'd test with a ping.  If that's successful, I'd start looking at the port.  Finally, make sure the MySQL actually allows your Lucee server IP to connect.  In fact, I'd check that first.